# Repositioning elements in an array with new different indexes

Tags: java, arrays, loops, project

I'm working on a basic hashtable project in Java for my course and I'm getting frustrated already.
I just want to know how to reposition elements (Strings) in an array. How would I put the elements in a new position given new indexes that came from dividing it's hashcode to the size of the array. Also when a collision occurs for example 2 strings has the same index, the tendency is to double the size of the array, get the new index value off all existing word in the array and putting it back in their new indexes.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnnfk.png)

[example cont.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6goPD.png)

I really need answers by the 30th of April, I really hope some good folks would answer my questions because I've been working on it since the start of the month.

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: You must surely have some code to share if you have been working on this for 25 days

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this piece of code that takes an array of strings that needs to be reordered according to your method and returns a HashMap (`map`) where the key is a String and its Value is its new index, always calculated according to your method.

I created temporarily the `hashcode(String str)` function, you will have to insert yours.

Now the only thing you'll need to do is to study the `map` in order to create your new reordered array of strings.

**CODE**

```
public static Map<String, Integer> newIndexesMap(String[] a) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int length = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int newIndex = hashcode(a[i]) % length;
            // Check that the new index is not already used by another key
            if (map.containsValue(newIndex)) {
                length = length * 2;
                i = -1;
                map.clear();
            } else
                map.put(a[i], newIndex);
        }
        return map;
}
```

Comment: one more thing, we could not use the built in hashcode functions, just loops and arrays

Comment: Well, the best thing to do in your case so, is to write your own hashcode function. It accepts an element as parameter, it controls if it can do the hash of that element, it returns the right hash. If you have more questions let me know, if not mark your question as resolved, thanks!

Comment: that's exactly what i needed